# How to count elements matched with :contains?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can I count the matched classes with jQuery's `:contains`?

If I have the following code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ll">John Resig</div>

<div class="ll">George Martin</div>
<div>Malcom John Sinclair</div>
<div class="ll">J. Ohn</div>


<script>
$("div.ll").hide()
$("div.ll:contains('John')").show();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I count the matched elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size) or `length`

```
$("div.ll:contains('John')").size();
$("div.ll:contains('John')").length;
```

And you should use `length`

because the docs say

> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property of the jQuery object, which returns

> [the] number of elements currently matched.

So in your example, to get the number of matched elements, you would do something like

```
var count = $("div.ll:contains('John')").length;
```

Also, according the jQuery docs for length (linked above),

> The [`.size()`](http://api.jquery.com/size) method will return the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
$("div.ll:contains('John')").length
```